# How to directly go to the device library for Audio in Banuba Video Editor?

Tags: android, ios, audio, video

I want to upload music from my device to my Video Editor but I do not see exact directions on how to do it. I need the info for both iOS and Android platforms if possible.

I've found no info on either your website or Github.

Answer (score 0):

**For Android**, please, add the following code to the VideoEditorModule:

```
single {
object : AudioBrowserConfigProvider {
override var config = AudioBrowserConfig.LOCAL
}
}
```

**For iOS**, please, set the musicSource`to`localStorageWithMyFiles:

```
AudioBrowserConfig.shared.musicSource = .localStorageWithMyFiles
```

Keep in mind that the above only applies to audio tracks that are stored in the phone's memory through the Apple Music app.